# I called an intent to launch activity. But it take more time to launch

Tags: android, android-activity, launch

activity take more time to launch. Here is my code

```
 Intent intent =new Intent(getActivity(), McallContactsActivity.class);
 startActivity(intent);
```

I have  disabled instant run, then tried. But it will take more time to lanch activity.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mcall_contacts_activity);
    toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) 
    findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    recycleListFriend = (RecyclerView) 
    findViewById(R.id.recycleListFriend);
    swipeRefreshLayout  = (SwipeRefreshLayout) 
    findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);
    phoneContact = new PhoneContact();
    if(toolbar != null) {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Users");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });

    checkContactPermission();
    setupAdapter();
    phoneContactList = getContacts(McallContactsActivity.this);
    DatabaseReference ref = 
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user");
    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
            new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

              dataSnapshot.getValue().keySet().iterator().next().toString();
                    String id = ((HashMap) 
             dataSnapshot.getValue()).keySet().iterator().next().toString();
                    collectPhoneNumbers((Map<String,Object>) 
             dataSnapshot.getValue());
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    //handle databaseError
                }
            });
}
```

> This is MCallContactsActivity's onCreate method. No onResume() method for this activity

Comment: Your oncreate() method takes more time. Post oncreate method of McallContactsActivity

Comment: post your onCreate and onResume  method of McallContactActivity.class

Comment: Mostly the time taken to open an activity is because of the code in Oncreate on new activity and Onpause of the old acivity.

Comment: Avoid doing longer operations inside Main thread. because of that only It is taking more time to launch another Activity.

Comment: @JyotiJK I have added onCreate method. Could you please check. Thank you

Comment: @VineshChauhan added. please check . Thank you

Comment: I think you can do `getContacts` at background. Not in main thread

Comment: Try to add async task to run getContacts in bAckground

Comment: @JyotiJK added getContacts in AsyncTask, it worked. Thank you.

Comment: @VineshChauhan Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
class getContects extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void voids) {

         // Your Code Here 

            return null;
        }
    }
```

getContacts Taking too much to load thats why activity taking time to load so use Async task when activity created